# NSCoding duplicates Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, encode, nscoding

I have custom class where I declare

```
var metros: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
```

I have to save this into user defaults so I init NSCoding

```
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    metros = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("metros")! as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
}

@objc func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(metros, forKey: "metros")
}
```

The problem is while decoding it returns the same dictionary multiple times like `[key1: value1, key2: value2]` and `[key2 : value2, key1 : value1]` and so on. How should I avoid this?

To be more exact I have 31 duplicates, 55 duplicates of some of the values

UPDATE: 
I solved this issue like

```
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if let metroObject = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("metros")! as? [[String: AnyObject]]) {
        for object in metroObject {
            var alreadyExists = false
            for objectAppended in metros {
                if String(objectAppended["name"]) == String(object["name"]) {
                    alreadyExists = true
                }
            }
            if alreadyExists == false {
                metros.append(object)
                print(object["name"])
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

but really curious if there is another way